# How to get transit time from Sabre flight API?

Tags: rest, sabre

We're trying to get flight list from Sabre. Our API request body looks like this:

```
{
    "flightSegment": [
        {
            "from": "DAC",
            "to": "AUS",
            "journey_date": "2023-04-16",
            "fromName": "DAC Hazrat Shahjalal International Airport",
            "toName": "AUS Austin-Bergstrom International Airport"
        }
    ],
    "return_date": null,
    "adult": 1,
    "infant": 0,
    "ins": 0,
    "children": [],
    "seatClass": "Y",
    "token": "token"
}
```

The `endpoint` we're hitting is `/v4/offers/shop`.

We're getting our response but we're not sure, which exactly is the `transit/layover` time?

We tried to use their documentation but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct parameter to get the information. This has to be calculated from the arrival of the previous segment and the departure of the current segment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).